# Swap Space vs Backing Store

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, paging

I am currently reading about memory management in my operating systems textbook and am curious if there is a difference between a swap space and a backing store.  They both seem to do the same thing in general.  From what I understand when a page fault occurs an inactive page is found and stored in the swap space so the page that caused the fault can be stored.  A backing store seems to do the same thing except it's for an entire process not just a page.  Is this the main difference between the two? Or are there other things I am over looking?

Answer (score 2):

The term "backing store" is normally used in the context of graphical user interfaces. The backing story is a block of memory that holds the image of a window. If the window gets covered (even partially) then uncovered, the backing store is used to redraw.

Some systems (e.g., X, and Windoze) generally do not use a backing store (except for dialog boxes). They just have the application redraw the screen.

In ye olde days swap space was used to move entire processes to disk. The page file was used to store individual pages. Traditional swapping has gone away. However, Unix retains the term swap when it is technically paging.

In a general sense, a page file and a backing store are similar:

backing store is to video memory as is

page file is to physical memory.

However, backing story is not really related to paging as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

From **Chapter 10: Virtual Memory**, from the **Operating System Concepts** book:

> Some systems attempt to limit the amount of swap space used through
>   demand paging of binary executable files. Demand pages for such files
>   are brought directly from the file system. However, when page
>   replacement is called for, these frames can simply be overwritten
>   (because they are never modified), and the pages can be read in from
>   the file system again if needed. Using this approach, the file system
>   itself serves as the backing store. However, swap space must still be
>   used for pages not associated with a file (known as anonymous memory);
>   these pages include the stack and heap for a process. This method
>   appears to be a good compromise and is used in several systems,
>   including Linux and BSD UNIX.

From this, I gather than **swap space** is space specifically used on a file system to contain swapped out pages for later use.

The **backing store** can just be files that are used to generate the demand page, e.g. actually binaries that need to be read. They don't have to be created for the purpose of virtual memory, they *can* be the files themselves.

However, in another chapter (9.5: Swapping), the books mentions

> However, a process, or a portion of a process, can be swapped
>   temporarily out of memory to a backing store and then brought back
>   into memory for continued execution (Figure 9.19).

---

I think **backing store** includes **swap space**, but not all forms of backing store is considered swap space. For example, your file system containing the actual program to run is considered a backing store, but not swap space.